# IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error Randomly

Tags: i2c

I have 8 MCP23017 IO expander about 3m away from the Raspberry PI2, and the system usually work but sometimes i get error, from different MCP. I don't know why is it software or hardware problem. I use P82B96 Dual bidirectional bus buffer at the raspberry and each MCP23017 IO expander. And sometimes it can not see anything with i2cdetect and after a secound it can(please see the image)
Thank you[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUeqS.jpg)

Comment: The length of the cable 3m seems like a possible cause have you tried with a much shorted cable? Or the buffer. Simplifying the circuit would seem the best way to debug this (e.g. shorted cable length, then remove the buffers etc. then starting with 1 MCP23017 and building up the circuit one at a time. FWIW it might help if you describe a little about your project. So we could perhaps suggest alternative solutions. For exaample could you shorten the cable, do away wwith the buffers and move the Pi closer to the sensor, and then use another means of commnicating back to a controller.

Comment: First i tried without buffers but maybe it was worst. 6 MCP drive solenoids about 3m from raspberry and the other 1 MCP is 2m in other direction switch relay (230VAC pump and powerled supply), so it is not possible to move closer. Earlier experience when led was connected instead of solenoids it seems worked (but it is not laws) This buffer (based on its manual) could work 250m distance. [link](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/P82B96.pdf) the connection what i use is figure 12 with simple net cable.

Comment: Other thing you might try to do to get the I2C to work over longer distances is to run it more slowly (or use better, *lower capacitance* cables) - is that an option?  If you are bit-banging it might be possible (increase the delays in the bits that time pulsing the lines) but I do not know if higher level libraries allow this?

Comment: A little bit lower speed is ok, i tried 50kHz, but it seems didn't helped. I use net cable with twisted pairs, is there more lower capacitance cable? And please don't forget i use between the MCP this buffer IC, this should allow more distance, please check it's datasheet, maybe you can find the best solution in it. I use the figure 12. And what do you mean in this "increase the delays in the bits that time pulsing the lines" ? How could i do it?